# How to use ForkJoinPool to use multiple cores in java?

Tags: java, parallel-processing, fork-join, forkjoinpool

So I am trying to understand about how ForkJoinPool works. I am trying to achieve better performance using this for a large array of about 2 million elements and then adding their reciprocal. I understand that ForkJoinPool.commpnPool().invoke(task); calls compute() which forks the task in two tasks if it is not smaller and then computes and then joins them. So far, we are using two cores.

But if I want to xecute this on multiple cores, how do I do that and achieve 4 times better performance than the usual single thread run? Below is my code for default ForkJoinPool():

```
@Override
        protected void compute() {
            // TODO
            if (endIndexExclusive - startIndexInclusive <= seq_count) {
                for (int i = startIndexInclusive; i < endIndexExclusive; i++)
                    value += 1 / input[i];
            } else {

                ReciprocalArraySumTask left = new ReciprocalArraySumTask(startIndexInclusive,
                        (endIndexExclusive + startIndexInclusive) / 2, input);
                ReciprocalArraySumTask right = new ReciprocalArraySumTask((endIndexExclusive + startIndexInclusive) / 2,
                        endIndexExclusive, input);
                left.fork();
                right.compute();
                left.join();
                value = left.value + right.value;
            }
        }
    }


protected static double parArraySum(final double[] input) {
        assert input.length % 2 == 0;

        double sum = 0;

        // Compute sum of reciprocals of array elements
        ReciprocalArraySumTask task = new ReciprocalArraySumTask(0, input.length, input);
        ForkJoinPool.commonPool().invoke(task);
        return task.getValue();
    }

//Here I am trying to achieve with 4 cores
protected static double parManyTaskArraySum(final double[] input,
                                                final int numTasks) {
        double sum = 0;
        System.out.println("Total tasks = " + numTasks);
        System.setProperty("java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.common.parallelism", String.valueOf(numTasks));
        // Compute sum of reciprocals of array elements
        int chunkSize = ReciprocalArraySum.getChunkSize(numTasks, input.length);
        System.out.println("Chunk size = " + chunkSize);
        ReciprocalArraySumTask task = new ReciprocalArraySumTask(0, input.length, input);
        ForkJoinPool pool = new ForkJoinPool();
//        pool.
        ForkJoinPool.commonPool().invoke(task);
        return task.getValue();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to use 4 cores but you are giving a job which will need only two cores. In the following example, getChunkStartInclusive and getChunkEndExclusive methods give the range for beginning and ending indexes of each chunk. I believe the following code can solve your problem and give you some implementation idea.

```
protected static double parManyTaskArraySum(final double[] input,
        final int numTasks) {
    double sum = 0;
    System.setProperty("java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.common.parallelism", String.valueOf(numTasks));
    List<ReciprocalArraySumTask> ts = new ArrayList<ReciprocalArraySumTask>(numTasks);

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < numTasks - 1 ; i++) {
        ts.add(new ReciprocalArraySumTask(getChunkStartInclusive(i,numTasks,input.length),getChunkEndExclusive(i,numTasks,input.length),input));
        ts.get(i).fork();
    }
    ts.add( new ReciprocalArraySumTask(getChunkStartInclusive(i, numTasks, input.length), getChunkEndExclusive(i, numTasks, input.length), input));
    ts.get(i).compute();

    for (int j = 0; j < numTasks - 1; j++) {
        ts.get(j).join();
    }

    for (int j = 0; j < numTasks; j++) {
        sum += ts.get(j).getValue();
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Comment: so my compute method remains the same even with this implementation?

Comment: No, for loop can stay in compute without if-else and you can carry else part into parArraySum because you do not need to use this part for parManyTaskArraySum.

Comment: i tried it, but i do not get any performance improvement. I have 2 cores with each having 2 logical processors, giving total number of cores to be 4. Am i missing anything or is it expected given this config?

Comment: How many cores do you have on your computer? Also, it really depends on your computer's performance but I expect a performance upgrade. Moreover, you can also check my repository, I made it public for you. https://gitlab.com/emredemircan/miniproject_1

Comment: For some reason, I don't think this might be the correct way to code this out. You are just spreading it across the 4 processors and that too, I am not sure if it is doing in your code or not, since you are using default ForkJoinPool() which only uses 2 cores. Moreover, I think it should work by dividing into various tasks and then pooling them one by one on each of those 4 available cores.

Answer (score 1):

This is my approach:

- Threshold is the limit when the compute starts to calculate and stops to stack recursive calls, this works better if each processor is used twice or more (there is a limit of course), that's because I use `numTask * 2`.

  ```
   protected static double parManyTaskArraySum(final double[] input,
                                           final int numTasks) {
       int start;
       int end;

       int size = input.length;
       int threshold = size / (numTasks * 2);

       List<ReciprocalArraySumTask> actions = new ArrayList<>();

       for (int i = 0; i < numTasks; i++) {
           start = getChunkStartInclusive(i, numTasks, size);
           end = getChunkEndExclusive(i, numTasks, size);
           actions.add(new ReciprocalArraySumTask(start, end, input, threshold, I));
       }
       ForkJoinTask.invokeAll(actions);

       return actions.stream().map(ReciprocalArraySumTask::getValue).reduce(new Double(0), Double::sum);

    }
  ```